# postgresql- how to define a variable by a function call in an if statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION findMyList( p_user_id bigint)
 .... 

DECLARE

   myVar_id bigint;

...

      IF myVar_id = select p_user_id from myFunction(p_user_id )  THEN
       NULL;
     ELSE
       myVar_id := NULL;
     END IF;
```

however there appears to be a syntax issue that I can't work out why it does not allow this as it doesnt seem unreasonable:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 78:      IF myVar_id = select p_user_id from myFunction...
```

why does it not let me define the variable as such?

Comment: You need parentheses around a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
myVar_id := (SELECT p_user_id from myFunction(p_user_id))
```